# How to set default syntax highlighting in Kate

Tags: syntax-highlighting, kate

By default when a new document is opened in Kate, the highlighting is set to *normal*, i.e. none.

Is there any way to change this behavior, with a result that when a new "untitled" document is opened C syntax highlighting is enabled without having to manually change the highlighting mode?

Answer (score -1):

`kate --help` didn't give me a command line option to preselect the syntax highlighting, and I also found no setting for empty documents. However, I've got a quite dated KDE running here, so you should check for yourself.

The syntax highlighting of `kate` is triggered by file extensions. As soon as you save the file with the correct extension the highlighting is applied, so this may be a workaround.